# JMeter - Once Only Controller for Authentication with Stepping Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have been using a plain old vanilla Thread Group in JMeter for a while now, using a `Once Only Controller` to authenticate each thread before accessing the page in my app I wish to profile.

This has been working perfectly. However I now want to try using a `Stepping Thread Group` with my app so I tried this same approach but it's not working - when I look at the results of the main request for the page I am trying to profile, I can see it's instead redirecting to the login screen, since the thread is not logged in.

I then got rid of the `Once Only Controller` and tried to simply have 2 requests under the Stepping Thread Group - first one to simply login, then a separate request to hit my app page to profile. However I'm running into the same issue (even though it does appear the login request is being executed - I'm seeing correct responses and activity there in the View Results listener, so maybe it's just not happening in the correct order?).

Sorry if I'm missing something, I'm still relatively new to JMeter. Any help or guidance greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing an `HTTP Cookie Manager`. Though interestingly some of the responses for the page I wish to profile are coming back to the Login page as unauthenticated but most are making it through now.